# Bubble up events from a one-to-many relationship

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

I can bubble up an event from a one-to-one relationship like this

```
Public Class Husband

    Public WithEvents Wife As Wife

    Public Sub WifeChangedLastName() Handles Wife.LastNameChanged
        MsgBox("Wife Changed Last Name")
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Wife

    Public _LastName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
        Get
            Return Me._LastName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            Me._LastName = Value
            Raise Event LastNameChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event LastNameChanged As EventHandler

End Class
```

But how do I do something similar with a one-to-many relationship?  Here's what I have so far:

```
Public Class Organization

    Public WithEvents Group As New Group 'A one-to-one relationship

    Public Sub PersonAddedToGroup() Handles Group.PersonAdded
        MsgBox("A person has been added to the group.") 'This works
    End Sub

    'I want to do something here when a person's name changes

End Class

Public Class Group

    Public WithEvents People As List(Of Person) 'A one-to-many relationship

    Public Sub Add(ByVal Person As Person)
        Me.People.Add(Person)

        RaiseEvent PersonAdded(Me, EventArgs.Empty)      
    End Sub

    Public Event PersonAdded As EventHandler

End Class

Public Class Person

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return Me._Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            Me._Name = Value
            RaiseEvent PersonChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PersonChanged As EventHandler

End Class
```

I'd like to handle a PersonChanged event inside Organization.  How do I do this?

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know a technique to make this work.  `PersonChanged` is an event of `Person` which is stored in a list in `Group`.  I don't know how to get the event to bubble up as far as `Group`, much less `Organization`.

Comment: I've posted an answer that should get you started... I kind of skipped the bubbling though and made it go straight to the top. Basically what it comes down to is that you won't be able to use `WithEvents` and tack on `Handles ...` at the end of the method. You'll have to use `AddHandler`/`RemoveHandler` instead. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the event-handler for each person... they can all be handled by the same method though. Here's what I'd suggest.

1. Change the `PersonAdded` event to pass the new `Person` object that was added. You'll need to update where you declared the event/handler to include this, I believe...

   ```
   'Inside Group.Add(person As Person)
   RaiseEvent PersonAdded(Me, person)
   ```
2. In the event handler for `PersonAdded`, subscribe to the `PersonChanged` event for that particular person:

   ```
   Public Sub PersonAddedToGroup(person As Person) Handles Group.PersonAdded
       MsgBox("A person has been added to the group.") 'This works
       AddHandler person.PersonChanged, AddressOf OnPersonChanged
   End Sub
   ```

Something like that should accomplish what you want (this is rough code, not testing in VS). If you are adding and removing people, remember that events can lead to memory leaks (i.e. you'll want to call `RemoveHandler` when the object subscribing to the events goes away. In this case `Organization` will probably outlast the `Person` object, so it's not that much of an issue, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: EventHandler requires the parameters Object and System.EventArgs.  I don't know how to pass person easily.  Also, this doesn't seem like bubbling up as much as trying to hook into each `PersonChanged` handler from within `Organization`.

Comment: Actually, since the `Person` that changed is the `sender`, you could potentially do `DirectCast(sender, Person)` to get the person. Just to clarify.... `Group` needs to handle `PersonChanged` and raise the same event which `Organization` will handle? Or would it raise a new event?

Answer (score 0):

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627637/1025728) from LarsTech.  He suggested using a (System.ComponentModel.)BindingList which handles property change events.